# Convert H2OFrame object from milliseconds to Minutes?

Tags: r, h2o

The H2O-R-Package is providing functions to extract/convert entries of an H2OFrame object from milliseconds to :

- Year
  h2o.year()
- Month
  h2o.month()
- Hour
  h2o.hour()
- Day
  h2o.day()
- Day of the week
  h2o.dayOfWeek()
- but nothing for minutes ...

How to convert the entries of an H2OFrame object from milliseconds to Minutes since the begining of Hour ?

```
data.hex = h2o.importFile(filetoload, sep = "," )
date.hex = data.hex[,3] 

#Number of minutes since the begining of Hour
date_epoch = as.data.frame(date.hex)
date_formated = apply(date_epoch , 1, function(x){
    date_format =  as.POSIXlt(x, origin="1970-01-01", tz="HKT")
    return(date_format)
} )

minu =  unlist(lapply(date_formated, function(x){

    return(x$min)
}))
minu.hex = as.h2o(minu)
```

The computing time of this code is extremely long compare to :

```
#Hour of day
heure.hex = hour(date.hex)
```

Is there any better solutions?
Why there is not any h2o.minute() fonction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a better solution using modulo :

```
data.hex = h2o.importFile(filetoload, sep = "," )
date.hex = data.hex[,3] 

#Number of minutes since the begining of Hour
#Divide by 1000 to work with seconds and Extract minutes + seconds
#Remove seconds and format in minutes
minu.hex = ((date.hex/1000)%%(60*60))%/%60
```